# Mouse Movement in Pygame when selecting objects does not seem to work

Tags: python, pygame

I am making a small game using pygame, and at the moment I have five balls falling from the top of the screen and landing on a pile of boxes to destroy knock them down. At the moment everything seems to work fine however, I was trying to select the balls with my mouse so that when the balls fall down I would be able to select them again and return them to their original position.

Here is my code for the program

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
from pygame.color import *
import pymunk as pm
from pymunk import Vec2d
import sys
## ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

class Ball(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,screen):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load('ball1.jpg')
        self.original = pygame.image.load('ball1.jpg')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.area = screen.get_rect()

    def add_ball(self, space, offset):#offset
        self.mass = 4
        self.radius = 15
        self.inertia = pm.moment_for_circle(self.mass, 0, self.radius, (0,0))

        self.body = pm.Body(self.mass, self.inertia)
        self.body.position = offset+200, 550
        self.rect.center = to_pygame(self.body.position)

        self.shape = pm.Circle(self.body, self.radius, (0,0))
        space.add(self.body, self.shape)

    def draw(self,screen):
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, (255,255,255), self.rect.center, int(15), 3)

    def update(self):
        print("{0} {1}".format(self.rect.center, self.body.position))
        self.rect.center = to_pygame(self.body.position)


## ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

class Box(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,screen):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

        self.image = pygame.image.load('box1.jpg')
        self.original = pygame.image.load('box1.jpg')
        #self.image = pygame.image.load('snake.jpg')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.area = screen.get_rect()


    def add_box(self, space, posX, posY):
        global screen
        self.size= 30
        self.points = [(-self.size, -self.size), (-self.size, self.size), (self.size,self.size), (self.size, -self.size)]
        self.mass = 0.3
        self.moment = pm.moment_for_poly(self.mass, self.points, (0,0))

        self.body = pm.Body(self.mass, self.moment)
        self.body.position = Vec2d(posX, posY)
        #print("Box a {0}".format(self.body.position))
        self.rect.center = to_pygame(self.body.position)
        #print("Box b {0}".format(self.rect))
        self.shape = pm.Poly(self.body, self.points, (0,0))
        self.shape.friction = 1
        #self.shape.group = 1

        space.add(self.body, self.shape)


    def draw(self,screen):
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255,255,255), self.rect, 2)

    def update(self):
        self.rect.center = to_pygame(self.body.position) #pysics simulations is movin the body

## ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

class Snake(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,screen):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

        self.image = pygame.image.load('snake.jpg')
        self.original = pygame.image.load('snake.jpg')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.area = screen.get_rect()

    def add_snake(self, space, posX, posY):
        global screen
        self.size= 30
        self.points = [(-self.size, -self.size), (-self.size, self.size), (self.size,self.size), (self.size, -self.size)]
        self.mass = 0.1
        self.moment = pm.moment_for_poly(self.mass, self.points, (0,0))

        self.body = pm.Body(self.mass, self.moment)
        self.body.position = Vec2d(posX, posY)
        #print("Box a {0}".format(self.body.position))
        self.rect.center = to_pygame(self.body.position)
        #print("Box b {0}".format(self.rect))
        self.shape = pm.Poly(self.body, self.points, (0,0))
        self.shape.friction = 0.1
        #self.shape.group = 1

        space.add(self.body, self.shape)


    def draw(self,screen):
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (5,5,255), self.rect, 2)

    def update(self):
        self.rect.center = to_pygame(self.body.position) #pysics simulations is movin the body
#=========================Eggs===============================================

class Eggs(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,screen):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

        self.image = pygame.image.load('egg.jpg')
        self.original = pygame.image.load('egg.jpg')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.area = screen.get_rect()

    def add_Egg(self, space, posX, posY):
        global screen
        self.size= 35
        self.points = [(-self.size, -self.size), (-self.size, self.size), (self.size,self.size), (self.size, -self.size)]
        self.mass = 0.3
        self.moment = pm.moment_for_poly(self.mass, self.points, (0,0))

        self.body = pm.Body(self.mass, self.moment)
        self.body.position = Vec2d(posX, posY)
        #print("Box a {0}".format(self.body.position))
        self.rect.center = to_pygame(self.body.position)
        #print("Box b {0}".format(self.rect))
        self.shape = pm.Poly(self.body, self.points, (0,0))
        self.shape.friction = 0.1
        #self.shape.group = 1

        space.add(self.body, self.shape)

    def draw(self,screen):
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (5,5,255), self.rect, 2)

    def update(self):
        self.rect.center = to_pygame(self.body.position) #pysics simulations is movin the body

## ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

def to_pygame(p):
    """Small hack to convert pymunk to pygame coordinates"""
    return int(p[0]), int(-p[1]+600)

def from_pygame(p):
    return to_pygame(p)


def main():
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((600, 600))

    pygame.display.set_caption("Piling boxes")
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    space = pm.Space()
    space.gravity = (0.0, -900.0)
    space.damping = 0.5
    balls= []
    selected = None

    ### ground
    body = pm.Body()
    shape = pm.Segment(body, (0,100), (600,100), .0)
    shape.friction = 1.0
    space.add(shape)

    allsprites = pygame.sprite.Group()

    offsetY = 62
    offsetX = 92
    posX = 180
    posY = 130

    for j in range(3):
        for i in range(5):
            box = Box(screen) #Add more boxes
            box.add_box(space, posX, posY)
            allsprites.add(box)
            posY = posY + offsetY
        posY = 130
        posX = posX + offsetX

##    for i in range(5):
##        x = 200
##        for j in range(5):
##            # what is the mass of the box?
##            mass = randint(1,3)
##            # what size is the box?
##            # size = randint(10, 35)
##            size = 20
##            # calculate its position & hold it in a Vec2d
##            # comment out one of these to change the pile
##            x = x + size + 10
##            pos = Vec2d(x,y)
##            box = add_box(space, size, pos, mass)
##            boxes.append(box)

##        y = y + size

    snake = Snake(screen)
    snake.add_snake(space, posX, posY) #add the snake after adding the boxes
    allsprites.add(snake)

    posX = posX + offsetX #increase x position so that the egg appears next to the snake
    egg = Eggs(screen)
    egg.add_Egg(space,posX,posY)#pass space ,position x and position y
    allsprites.add(egg)
    selected = None


    posY =0
    offset = 0
    for i in range(5):

        balls = Ball(screen)
        balls.add_ball(space, offset)
        offset = offset + 16
        allsprites.add(balls)
        print(balls)

    #background = pygame.Surface(screen.get_size())
    #background = background.convert()
    #background.fill((0,0,0))

    #screen.blit(background, (0,0))
    test_image = pygame.image.load("AngryCloneBg.jpg")
    #screen.blit(test_image, (0,0)) #coordinates (0,500))

    #pygame.display.flip()


    while 1:
        clock.tick(60)
        space.step(1/90.0)

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit(0)
            elif event.type == KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                    pygame.quit()
                    sys.exit(0)
                if event.key == K_p:
                    ball[0].body.apply_impulse((450,0))
                if event.key == K_s:
                    ball[0].body.apply_impulse((-450,0))
                elif event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                   p = from_pygame(Vec2d(event.pos))
                   selected = space.point_query_first(p)
            elif event.type == MOUSEBUTTONUP:
                if selected != None:
                    selected = None
            elif event.type == MOUSEMOTION:
                if selected != None:
                    selected.body.position = from_pygame(event.pos)


        allsprites.update()
        screen.blit(test_image, (0,0))
        #pygame.draw.line(screen, THECOLORS["red"], to_pygame((150,100)), to_pygame((450,100)), 3)
        allsprites.draw(screen)
        for item in allsprites:
            item.draw(screen)
        pygame.display.flip()

## ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Here is the bit of code where I add the mouse movement events for the ball

```
while 1:
    clock.tick(60)
    space.step(1/90.0)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit(0)
        elif event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit(0)

            if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
               p = from_pygame(Vec2d(event.pos))
               selected = space.point_query_first(p)
        elif event.type == MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            if selected != None:
                selected = None
        elif event.type == MOUSEMOTION:
            if selected != None:
                selected.body.position = from_pygame(event.pos)


    allsprites.update()
    screen.blit(test_image, (0,0))
    #pygame.draw.line(screen, THECOLORS["red"], to_pygame((150,100)), to_pygame((450,100)), 3)
    allsprites.draw(screen)
    for item in allsprites:
        item.draw(screen)
    pygame.display.flip()
```

I have added the needed events in the while loop but when I click and try to drag the balls upwards they seem to not respond to the mouse click

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only problem seem to be that you are indenting the code

```
elif event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
    p = from_pygame(Vec2d(event.pos))
    selected = space.point_query_first(p)
```

one level too much. Also change it to an `if` instead of an `elif`. I tried changing that and then I could move the balls using the mouse.

Hope you get it working now. :)

Comment: do you know how I can add a catapult to fire balls from? so that the balls can be fired from the catapult?

Comment: Nope sorry. Try putting more pressure on an answer to your question about that. Ask for more details, tell people what you have tried and so on.